# How to make a folder accessible with remote domain url?

Tags: domain, hosting

I have a website `http://example.com`, which contains two folders `http://example.com/site/` and `http://example.com/blog/`, placed at `hosting X`. Domain `example.com` is hosted by the same `hosting X`.

Now the folder `/blog/` migrates to `hosting Y`.

How can i achieve, that the folder `/blog/` and all nested subfolders and URLs are available by the old URL like `http://example.com/blog/` or `https://example.com/blog/article1/`, with domain name, hosted by `hosting X`?

I think into direction of `CNAME`, but not sure, how exactly is it to manage.

Comment: The correct technical jargon to map a specific URL path from one server to another is to “reverse proxy” (you can’t do that via a CNAME DNS record) - most web servers provide a solution for that. The ProxyPass directive in for example Apache and Nginx does that.

Comment: @HermanB Thank you! Correct terminology - this is indeed, what i'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL paths are a HTTP level concept and CNAMEs are DNS concept. This means CNAMEs cannot be used to make any changes to HTTP level mappings.

Instead, you need to add HTTP reverse proxying in your setup. Your server that hosts `http://example.com`, needs to forward requests arriving at `http://example.com/blog/` to hosting provider Y.

This means that all user visitor traffic will go via provider X, which will fetch part of the content from provider Y.

Personally, I think reverse proxying is not a good idea in this context. I would move the `/blog` to `http://blog.example.com` and then issue 301 redirects from `http://example.com/blog` to `http://blog.example.com`.

Comment: Could you please explain, why do you mean, it would be not a good idea? I plan to use this temporary, no longer as a month, until the whole site migrates to the new hoster. My first idea was placing the blog at subdomain too, but in terms of SEO changing of the URL would be a very bad idea.

Comment: For temporary usage this is an OK solution. It will add latency for the traffic to `/blog/` destination due to the proxying, but for transition period it is OK.

Comment: Ok, understand. Thank you!